# Showing that whether a construction is the maximum /minimum or not

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

16 friends decided to form clubs. Each club will have 4 members, and any two clubs may have at most two member in common. What is the greatest/least possible number of clubs they can form.

> Got 7 clubs (not sure if it is the maximum)
> I made it so every club contains members $A$ and $B$. Then there are 14 members left, so 7 clubs. How to show whether this is the maximum or not ? And minimum i think is 4 by letting exactly 4 diff members in each of the four club , all conditions are satisfied but i dont know how to show its the minimum

Comment: If you construct your seven clubs, one being $\{A,B,C,D\}$ and another being $\{A,B,E,F\}$ then you can create another club $\{C,D,E,F\}$

Comment: Is this a homework problem? Also, for the least number of clubs, why not just have zero clubs?

Comment: Not a homework but from a friend most probably some olympiad

Comment: @Henry hmm then how to restrict for maximum ?

Comment: I know the answer; it is possible to form more than $100$ clubs under these constraints. I also know there is no way this is an Olympiad problem, since this is a famously complicated combinatorial design. But as written, there is insufficient context here for MSE standards.

Comment: 140 is the maximum: https://oeis.org/A001843

Comment: @RobPratt is there a proper method of getting that maximum ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  Let $n=16$.
For each $4$-subset $C \subset\{1,\dots,n\}$, let binary decision variable $x_C$ indicate whether $C$ is selected.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_C x_C$ subject to linear (conflict) constraints
$$x_C + x_D \le 1 \quad \text{if $|C \cap D|>2$}.$$

You can also interpret this as finding a maximum independent set in a graph with one node per $4$-subset and an edge between each pair of subsets whose intersection has cardinality greater than two.

The maximum for general $n$ is given in https://oeis.org/A001843.